# Could not find CoreAudio.h for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to port an application written for Mac to iPhone device. However, I get compilation error for

## import CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h // No such file

Could you please let me know how can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the update: I could compile my application on iphone device even though I have commented the import line. Any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty specific, there is no such file as CoreAudio.h for iPhone apps, and that's why the compiler can't find it.  You can't make Xcode find it because it's not there.

Therefore, commenting out the line removes the problem.

Assuming you're actually using CoreAudio, the reason the app compiles is because you did include the right headers.